# Concept: Where to save data which is relevant for every ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, session

I am working on a bigger website. This website is a single page application with 100% no requests and only ajax calls. The Ajax calls have different receivers because the website is very modular based. (e.g. the news module calls AjaxNews.aspx, the transport module calls AjaxTransport.aspx).

In frontside I have mostly basic JavaScript with a lot of jquery, backend is in ASP.Net with C# a MS SQL Database and Lynq.

Now a new request is, that we should have "divisions", a user can select a division and all modules are filtered on this division setting, e.g. division 10 has another news then division 50 and so on...

The division is a simple drop down on front end, because it is resetting every time you hit F5, no data from this division is saved ever on backend. BUT I need the information on the backend because EVERY request relies on this information because I have to filter in database queries on division setting!

So where to store such information and how to maintain?

The only Idea I have is to store it in a Session, so e.g. on a fresh start I write the session with the default division for every user and onchange of the division dropdown I change the user session division with an ajax call and on backend I can have this information whenever I need it because its session, right?
Is that the best solution?

Comment: Store the information in the URL, and use something like [Path.JS](http://www.javascriptoo.com/path-js).

Comment: The problem is when I have to store it in the URL on backend I have much different recievers, I have to declare recieve-methods of this information in every reciever!

Comment: Why not use a cookie?

Comment: Because its client side, my problem is the server side availability of this information

Comment: Cookies are sent up with every request so they can be inspected server side.

Comment: By the way - I'd avoid saving any kind of UI state on your server if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best solution is to have a dropdown client side with a data attribute foreach element (eg. data-val='division1') so onChange you can retrieve that value by jQuery (eg. $('#dropdownID').attr('data-val')) and passing it in your ajax call as parameter.

html/js Example:

```js
        data = "division=" + $('ddTest').attr('data-val');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/divisionsPage.aspx",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

```html
 <select id="ddTest">
   <option data-val='division1'>division one</option>
   <option data-val='division2'>division two</option>
 </select>
```